# How to turn on table name autocomplete feature in Toad?

Tags: toad

I'm using Toad version 11.0.0.116. I'm not getting default tablename options when I start typing table. How to turn the autocomplete feature on??

Answer (score 62):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> should show you a list of available tables.

For example typing:

```sql
SELECT * FROM U
```

and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> should show you a list of all the tables starting with "U"

Answer (score 26):

As an alternative you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a default schema:
Toad Options > Oracle > General > Default Schema.